# Not able to use r key of keyword in JSP page after writing below JQuery code

Tags: jquery, jsp

Here i am stopping page reloading using f5 and ctr+R it is working correctly but problem is that after writing this code i am not able to use r key in my jsp page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || (e.which || e.keyCode) == 82 ) e.preventDefault(); };
    // Stop F5 Key 
    $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
    $("#saveParts").click(function(e) {
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Well, if key code 82 is "r" then your code is doing exactly what you describe.  If you don't want to disable the "r" key then don't intercept it with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `(e.which || e.keyCode) == 82` to

`((e.which || e.keyCode) == 82 && (e.which || e.keyCode) == 17))`.

This way it checks if both are pressed.

Comment: Well it is working but my requirement is i want to stop page reloading using f5 and ctrl+r, after writing this i am able to reload the page using ctrl+r, but i don't want this.